# How to manage HttpClient in Windows application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows

I have a windows application for registration.In First form I make an static object from HttpClient class:

```
 static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

and then I initialize it from constructor:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6488/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

and In first form I click on AddNew User which create an instance of another form. In that form again I created this stsic variable and then initilize it through constructor. At first time It works fine. but after Clicking for second type I get this error on second form:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll

What is the best practice to manage this static variable?

Comment: Altough it does not answer your question but i dont see any reason to use HttpClient instance as static variable, http is state less by its nature i can not see any point of doing this.

Comment: @HagayGoshen should I omit static keyword?

Comment: Have you tried `static constructor` for your class? for example: `public class Foo { static HttpClient client; static Foo(){ client = new HttpClient(); } }`

Comment: Yes , just create new instance every time you need to do HTTP request, you should also consider using WebRequest instead of HttpClient

Comment: @HagayGoshen `HttpClient` is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5